# Dropdown list is not remain selected after refreshing the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html

I have a drop-down list like bellow:

```
    <select class="span2" id ="sort" name= "order_by">
           <option >Default</option>
           <option >Price</option>
           <option >Color</option>
    </select>
```

and i have on change event handler for this :

```
$('select#sort').change(

  function(){       
    $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
  });
```

when i select the price from the dropdown list the price should remain selected but its not happening after refreshing the window.I am using ruby on rails .

I have no idea whats happening here.

Is there any one who can guide me?

thanks

Comment: On page load, fetch value from localstorage and add the selected attribute dynamically. Then on change of select box, add code to edit the localstorage value as well.. Hope you get the idea..

Comment: I am new to jquery and javasrcipt so its a bit tough to get this.Do you have any sample code @RoyMJ . Thanks

Comment: Ive given it a try.. Use the ruby solution also that is provided by @rubyist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following(Javascript/jQuery Solution) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selected_val = localStorage.getItem("sort");
    $("#sort").val(selected_val);//This would set the value from local-storage as selected value

    $("#sort").change(function(){
       var selected =  $("#sort").val();
       localStorage.setItem("sort", selected);//Setting the selected value in localstorage
       $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    });
});
```

**Please note that : If you are populating via database then while rendering the page template, you should be adding `selected` attribute then or just add that particular value as the localstorage value.**

Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the value on the server side anywhere, so when the page gets re-rendered the value gets selected automatically according to the selected value

Answer (score 0):

Use Rails select_tag helper instead of javascript

```
<%= select_tag(:order_by, options_for_select([['Default', 'Default'], ['Price', 'Price'], ['Color', 'Color']], selected: params[:order_by] )) %>
```

Comment: i tried your solution but i got this error

uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Default

Comment: Now try because all these are string values so put in single quote